# An error occurred while installing puma (3.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-toolbelt, aws-cloud9

Can someone please help me out with this. When running 'git push heroku master' getting the below error. See error logs and gem files below:

Source code on github at https://github.com/Jordanod1884/upskill_saas_tutorial

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '3.4.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '3.0.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '5.0.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.5.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Twitter Bootstrap library for front-end UI and layout
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'

# Use Font Awesome sass gem for adding icons
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.6.2'

# Use Hirb gem for better console data presentation
gem 'hirb', '0.7.3'

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end
group :production do
  # Use the PostgreSQL gem for Heroku production servers
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
ruby '2.6.3'
```

Error Message I am receiving :

```
ec2-user:~/environment/saasapp (master) $ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 311, done.
Counting objects: 100% (311/311), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (274/274), done.
Writing objects: 100% (311/311), 38.77 KiB | 1.02 MiB/s, done.
Total 311 (delta 137), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 BUNDLE_GLOBAL_PATH_APPENDS_RUBY_SCOPE=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.6
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.6
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Fetching erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.8.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.8.0
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching racc 1.6.0
remote:        Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.3
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.8.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.8.1
remote:        Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.1
remote:        Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.1
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.15.5
remote:        Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Installing method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching thor 1.2.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching hirb 0.7.3
remote:        Installing hirb 0.7.3
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Fetching pg 0.18.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching puma 3.4.0
remote:        Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
remote:        Fetching i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Installing i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.6.5
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching autoprefixer-rails 10.4.2.0
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 10.4.2.0
remote:        Fetching uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.13.3 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.13.3 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.0.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.0
remote:        Fetching activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.15.0
remote:        Installing loofah 2.15.0
remote:        Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Installing globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching activemodel 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.5.0
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.5.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Fetching sass 3.7.4
remote:        Fetching activejob 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionview 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activejob 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sass 3.7.4
remote:        Installing actionview 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching activerecord 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionpack 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.0.2
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-sass 4.6.2
remote:        Fetching actioncable 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 5.0.2
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.0.2
remote:        Installing font-awesome-sass 4.6.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching railties 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
remote:        Installing railties 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
remote:        Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Fetching rails 5.0.2
remote:        Installing rails 5.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http1
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20220329-290-a3cqm9.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
remote:        checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
remote:        checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
remote:        creating Makefile
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http1
remote:        make "DESTDIR=" clean
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http1
remote:        make "DESTDIR="
remote:        compiling http11_parser.c
remote:        In file included from ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:7:0:
remote:        ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function ‘puma_parser_execute’:
remote:        ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:17: warning: comparison between signed and
remote:        unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
remote:        ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
remote:        compiling io_buffer.c
remote:        compiling mini_ssl.c
remote:        mini_ssl.c: In function ‘get_dh1024’:
remote:        mini_ssl.c:90:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘DH {aka struct
remote:        dh_st}’
remote:           dh->p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof(dh1024_p), NULL);
remote:             ^~
remote:        mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_server’:
remote:        mini_ssl.c:161:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
remote:        [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
remote:           DH *dh = get_dh1024();
remote:           ^~
remote:        mini_ssl.c:165:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
remote:        [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
remote:           EC_KEY *ecdh = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
remote:           ^~~~~~
remote:        mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_client’:
remote:        mini_ssl.c:192:3: warning: ‘DTLSv1_method’ is deprecated
remote:        [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:           conn->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_method());
remote:           ^~~~
remote:        In file included from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13:0,
remote:                         from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:13,
remote:                         from mini_ssl.c:14:
remote:        /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1870:1: note: declared here
remote:         DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
remote:         ^
remote:        mini_ssl.c: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
remote:        Makefile:243: recipe for target 'mini_ssl.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1
remote:        
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0 for inspection
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/puma-3.4.0/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing puma (3.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          puma
remote:        Bundler Output: The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching rake 13.0.6
remote:        Installing rake 13.0.6
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing minitest 5.15.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
remote:        Fetching builder 3.2.4
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.4
remote:        Fetching erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching mini_portile2 2.8.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.8.0
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Fetching racc 1.6.0
remote:        Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching crass 1.0.6
remote:        Installing crass 1.0.6
remote:        Fetching rack 2.2.3
remote:        Installing rack 2.2.3
remote:        Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
remote:        Fetching arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Fetching execjs 2.8.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.8.1
remote:        Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.1
remote:        Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.1
remote:        Fetching ffi 1.15.5
remote:        Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.17.3
remote:        Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Fetching method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Installing method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching thor 1.2.1
remote:        Installing thor 1.2.1
remote:        Fetching hirb 0.7.3
remote:        Installing hirb 0.7.3
remote:        Fetching multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Fetching pg 0.18.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching puma 3.4.0
remote:        Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
remote:        Fetching i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Installing i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Fetching websocket-driver 0.6.5
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Fetching mail 2.7.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.7.1
remote:        Fetching autoprefixer-rails 10.4.2.0
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 10.4.2.0
remote:        Fetching uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Fetching nokogiri 1.13.3 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.13.3 (x86_64-linux)
remote:        Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
remote:        Fetching turbolinks 5.0.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.0
remote:        Fetching activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching loofah 2.15.0
remote:        Installing loofah 2.15.0
remote:        Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Fetching globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Installing globalid 1.0.0
remote:        Fetching activemodel 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching jbuilder 2.5.0
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.5.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
remote:        Fetching sass 3.7.4
remote:        Fetching activejob 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionview 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activejob 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sass 3.7.4
remote:        Installing actionview 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching activerecord 5.0.2
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionpack 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.0.2
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Fetching font-awesome-sass 4.6.2
remote:        Fetching actioncable 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching actionmailer 5.0.2
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.0.2
remote:        Installing font-awesome-sass 4.6.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching railties 5.0.2
remote:        Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
remote:        Installing railties 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
remote:        Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Fetching jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Fetching rails 5.0.2
remote:        Installing rails 5.0.2
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http1
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20220329-290-a3cqm9.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
remote:        checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
remote:        checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
remote:        creating Makefile
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http1
remote:        make "DESTDIR=" clean
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http1
remote:        make "DESTDIR="
remote:        compiling http11_parser.c
remote:        In file included from ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:7:0:
remote:        ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function ‘puma_parser_execute’:
remote:        ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:17: warning: comparison between signed and
remote:        unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
remote:        ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
remote:        compiling io_buffer.c
remote:        compiling mini_ssl.c
remote:        mini_ssl.c: In function ‘get_dh1024’:
remote:        mini_ssl.c:90:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘DH {aka struct
remote:        dh_st}’
remote:           dh->p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof(dh1024_p), NULL);
remote:             ^~
remote:        mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_server’:
remote:        mini_ssl.c:161:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
remote:        [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
remote:           DH *dh = get_dh1024();
remote:           ^~
remote:        mini_ssl.c:165:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
remote:        [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
remote:           EC_KEY *ecdh = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
remote:           ^~~~~~
remote:        mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_client’:
remote:        mini_ssl.c:192:3: warning: ‘DTLSv1_method’ is deprecated
remote:        [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:           conn->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_method());
remote:           ^~~~
remote:        In file included from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13:0,
remote:                         from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:13,
remote:                         from mini_ssl.c:14:
remote:        /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1870:1: note: declared here
remote:         DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
remote:         ^
remote:        mini_ssl.c: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
remote:        Makefile:243: recipe for target 'mini_ssl.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1
remote:        
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.4.0 for inspection
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_0f3ff8c6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/puma-3.4.0/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing puma (3.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          puma
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: bb98f64a1bc1414224533446d1e170b9e4503256
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version bb98f64a1bc1414224533446d1e170b9e4503256
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to still-wave-61102.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/still-wave-61102.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/still-wave-61102.git'
```

Can somebody please help me out here trying to resolve 2 weeks now. Have fully completed installing the puma 3.4.0 gem and have ran bundle update and bundle install both successfully but, still receiving the below error message when I run 'git push heroku master'. Again have added source code here too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling"—well, does it?

Comment: (One good reason to share code as _code_ is that I'd have been able to copy and paste most of that comment instead of painstakingly typing it out. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you. See [ask].)

Comment: I will share code now chris what snippets do you you need? the gemfile? I have alreadly successfully completed intsallin the pum gem 3.4.0 and ran bundle update and bundle install and still same error

Comment: I have now added this above chris

Comment: What do you mean by "I have alreadly successfully completed intsallin the pum gem 3.4.0"? Did you run the _exact_ command the error message tells you to run?

Comment: The other image is code from the terminal and it is included in code version beneath the gemfile code. I have ran the exact command in the error and its returning 1 gem added bundle updated successfully then when I rerun git push heroku master boom same error

Comment: It's irrelevant that it's from the terminal. Again, _please don't post screenshots of text_. That should be shared _as a code block_.

Comment: The terminal code is there too Its included as stated below.

Comment: Any ideas as to what else may be causing the issue? appreciate the help by the way

Comment: Any ideas chris?

Answer (score 0):

Experience the same error and fixed it by bumping the puma gem version to 3.7.0.

Change the line in `Gemfile`

```
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7.0'
```

Failure was due to OpenSSL 1.1 support which was added in 3.7.
Reference:
https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1380